# How can I combine the database by using MySQL and cocos2dx when developing a multiplatform game under ubuntu14.04?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, lamp

I'm working on a project using cocos2dx to develop a multiplatform game. My goal is to create a world based on HarryPotter, so I need to add database to my creatures and stores or somethin. But how can I using MySQL to achieve this goal? By the way, my OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and I wonder if the tools called LAMP(Linux+Apache+MySQL+PHP) can be useful for me in this issue.
  Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? What does your code look like? What have you tried?

Comment: I use cocos2dx as engine, so C++ is my language. and I just have download the cocos2dx.zip then try to build it on ubuntu. Before then, I build and apply successfully in Windows8.1, but Linux is a new environment to me.